# How to install Google Cloud SDK on AIX machine

Tags: unix, google-cloud-platform, ibm-cloud

I am trying in install complete Google Cloud SDK on IBM AIX 7.1.0 machine, however not able to find steps to install steps for setting up Google Cloud SDK on AIX. Due to this not able to run any gcloud/bq command. Only available instruction is to setup gsutil on AIX

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive#linux

Comment: What have you tried so far? the install steps are fairly generic

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeking a prepared package for installation on AIX, I am not aware of one.

AIX does support Python. You can install Python from the AIX toolbox repository.

Then download the Google Cloud SDK CLI source. You can then run the SDK CLI on your system. `gcloud` is a Python program.

The only issue is the package dependencies. I am not sure that all dependencies for all commands are available for AIX. You should not have a problem with the core features.